# Ajax message gets skipped to the url page not on required div element

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, forms

I have the below files...which has two form login and register(haven't posted the form part)
forms are action to auth.php and signup.php respectively and validate through user.php, everything works perfectly on login. However, when I register the user with name and image the success message get on the URL page, not on the modal-footer div
I want to update the message in footer DOM, which is div modal-footer.
I am using two different functions in script.js one has a data value of $.form.serialize, which handles the login part and Formdata handles the registration part....please guide to update the success message on the modal-footer div......Thanks.

**script.js**

```
$(function(){
    
    $('.form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);
        
        submitForm($form);       
        
        
    }); 

    $('.register').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

         $reg = $('.register');
         registerForm($reg);        
        
    });     

});


function submitForm($form){

    $footer = $form.parent('.modal-body').next('.modal-footer');
    
    $footer.html('<img src="public/images/ajax-loader.gif">');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        method: $form.attr('method'),        
        data: $form.serialize(),
        
        success: function(response){
            response = $.parseJSON(response);
            
            if(response.success){                   

            if(!response.signout){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    $footer.html( response.message );
                    window.location = response.url;
                },5000);
            }

             $footer.html( response.message );
            
             
         }
         else if(response.error){
            $footer.html( response.message );
         }

            console.log(response);

         }
     });
}

function registerForm($form){

    $footer = $form.parent('.modal-body').next('.modal-footer');  
    $footer.html('<img src="public/images/ajax-loader.gif">');
    var data = new FormData(this.form);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        method: $form.attr('method'), 
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response){
            response = $.parseJSON(response);
            if(response.success){                  
                if(!response.signout){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    $footer.html( response.message );
                    window.location = response.url;
                },5000);
            }
                $footer.html( response.message );

         }

         else if(response.error){

            $footer.html( response.message );
        }
            console.log(response)
        }

     });
}
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/init.php';


$status = $user->login($_POST, $db);

if( $status === 'success'){
    echo json_encode([
        'success'=> 'success', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-success">Authenticated successfully!</p>',
        'url' => 'profile.php',
    ]);
}
else if( $status === 'missing_fields'){
    echo json_encode([
        'error'=> 'error', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">All fields mandatory!</p>',
    ]);
}

else if( $status === 'error'){
    echo json_encode([
        'error'=> 'error', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">Incorrect email or password!</p>'
    ]);
}
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/init.php';


$status = $user->signup($_POST, $db);

if( $status === 'success'){
    echo json_encode([
        'success'=> 'success', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-success">You are signed up successfully!</p>',
        //'url' => 'index.php',
        'signout' => 1,
        
    ]);
}else if( $status === 'missing_fields'){
    echo json_encode([
        'error'=> 'error', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">All fields mandatory!</p>',
       
   ]);

}else if( $status === 'invalid format'){
    echo json_encode([
        'error'=> 'error', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">Only jpg,jpeg,pngfiles allowed!</p>',
        
    ]);
}else if( $status === 'error'){
    echo json_encode([
        'error'=> 'error', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">Failed to sign you up!</p>'
    ]);
}
```

?>

**user.php**

```
class User{


public function login($user, $db){

    if(empty($user['email']) OR empty($user['password'])){
        return 'missing_fields';
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=?";
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);

    

    if( is_object($statement) ){

        $statement->bindParam(1, $user['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();

        if($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){ // you the database and verify if the password and email match or not
            
            if(password_verify($user['password'], $row->password)){
                
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = [
                    'id'    =>  $row->id,
                    'name'  =>  $row->name,
                ]; 

                return 'success';
            }               

        }

    }
    return 'error';

}


public function signup($user, $db){


if(empty($user['name'])){
                return 'missing_fields';
                }else{  
                

if(isset($_FILES['image'])){     
    $imgfile=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $imgnewfile = $imgfile;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"public/images/".$imgnewfile);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(`name`,`profile_image`) VALUES(?,?)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);

        if(is_object($statement)){
        
            $statement->bindParam(1, $user['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            
            $statement->bindParam(2, $imgnewfile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            
            $statement->execute();

            if($statement->rowCount()){
                return 'success';
            }
}       }        

    }
    
return 'error';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check this part

```
   if(response.success){                   

        if(!response.signout){
                setTimeout(function(){
                $footer.html( response.message );
                window.location = response.url;
            },5000);
        }

         $footer.html( response.message );
```

**window.location** will redirect you to response url, if the signout is false. You are returning 1 from php. I don't know why you commented out the index.php in the php file as well. Is that the landing page you want the users to go? First of all check the content of the response with console.log or alert.

Comment: The only thing I am looking for here is login and register. Tihis code works fine expect the function registerForm($form)... it shows the message on the url page on within the model-footer  div...thanks. yes I have commented the index.php so it will work as 'signout' => 1,